# Debugging notify-send battery alert script

Tags: shell-script, cron

I used `crontab -e` to define the following:

```
*/5 * * * * env DISPLAY=:0 /home/max/.bin/battery-check.sh
```

The contents of the script are:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                          

# Battery level warning script

battery_level=`acpi -b | grep -P -o '[0-9]+(?=%)'`

if [[ "$battery_level" -le "80" && "$battery_level" -gt "10" ]]
    then
    notify-send "Battery low warning"  "
Battery level is ${battery_level}%"
elif [[ "$battery_level" -le "10" && "$battery_level" -gt "5" ]]
    then
    notify-send "Battery very low warning"  "
Battery level is ${battery_level}%
Use ac power now,
 or shutdown is imminent - close applications"
else [[ "$battery_level" -le "5" ]]
    # our custom actions for critical battery level
    notify-send "Battery critical warning"  "
Battery level is ${battery_level}%
Shutting system down now"
fi
```

Some statements, such as the first `-le "80"` are just for test/debug purposes. The problem with this script is that it results in a pop-up every 5 minutes reporting the last condition:

> Battery critical warning
>   Battery level is 100%
>   Shutting system down now

Comment: What does "is the absolute_not_respect of conditionals statements" mean?

Comment: What does "is the absolute_not_respect of conditionals statements" mean?... **a pop-up every 5 minutes reporting ONLY the last condition: "Battery critical warning...Shutting system down now".** whatever the battery percentage is

Comment: is it right syntax ? `else [[ "$battery_level" -le "5" ]]` , or `elif [[ "$battery_level" -le "5" ]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither of the first two conditions are met, so the `else` block is executed which consists of:

```
[[ "$battery_level" -le "5" ]]    # evaluates this, which does nothing
notify-send ...                   # shows the message you are seeing
```

Here's what you want:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                          

# Battery level warning script

battery_level=`acpi -b | grep -oP '[0-9]+(?=%)'`

if [[ $battery_level -le 80 && $battery_level -gt 10 ]]; then
    notify-send "Battery low warning"  "
Battery level is ${battery_level}%"
elif [[ $battery_level -le 10 && $battery_level -gt 5 ]]; then
    notify-send "Battery very low warning"  "
Battery level is ${battery_level}%
Use ac power now,
 or shutdown is imminent - close applications"
elif [[ $battery_level -le 5 ]]; then
    # our custom actions for critical battery level
    notify-send "Battery critical warning"  "
Battery level is ${battery_level}%
Shutting system down now"
fi
```